# Application does not show up after UAC confirmation

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, installshield, uac

I have a customer facing issues with two of my applications. One is created using Installshield and the other one is a C# WPF application. It is working for 100s of customers but only couple of them are seeing this issue. The problem is that when they try to launch a program, it prompts for a UAC confirmation dialog which is expected (Dialog says: Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?), user accepts by clicking on Yes, but the application does not launch after that.

What is stopping the application from launching and how to debug it?

Comment: Could a virus program or firewall cause this? One of the problems I had before was that there was a point in the code where there was no globalization. It was closing on that computer because of the date format.
I'm not sure, but maybe you can check the app's response via Event Viewer.

Comment: Check Windows Event Viewer logs, without Event viewer logs its difficult to reach on conclusion.

Comment: @saklanmaz Firewall and Antivirus are turned off. No problem with other executables but only with mine.

Comment: @MakAhmed Sure thanks. I will have to talk to customer to gather windows event viewer logs.

Answer (score 0):

A computer application is not always ideal in terms of execution behavior e.g. it won't always run on all machines, in your case to reach the problem solution its mandatory to find out the problem first

following are the standard approaches to detect the problem in production in client side have them implemented to detect yours.

**1. Installer Logs**

The installer logs are very important start from here it is possible that due to some reasons your application failed to install properly. So  implement an installer logger if you haven't till now.

**2. Custom or Third party Exception Logger**

Try to integrate your own or third party exception logger that maintains a daily basis and even the first application startup logs so that it will help you a lot what happens exactly when app was started. e.g. [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet)

**3. Windows Event Viewer**

Last but not least is the windows event viewer some time fatal errors do not let app start at all and your custom logger won't work check the events registered against your app in the event viewer, you will get your problem listed here.